# John not cracking an NTLM hash

Tags: passwords, john-the-ripper

I have been trying to do it with john the ripper as the following:

```
john --FORMAT=NT --wordlist=~/usr/share/wordlists/rockyou.txt hash.txt
```

the hash I am trying to crack is:

```
Computer:1001:aad3b435b51404eeaad3b435b51404ee:b5f121d454eb1a541ac69484bb0c6072::::
```

however, it didn't work. It keeps showing the following:

```
using default input encoding: UTF-8
loaded 1 password hash (NT [MD4 256/256 AVX2 8×3]))
press 'q' or ctrl-c to abort, almost any other key for status
0g 0:00:00:01 DONE (2023-07-21 10:10) 0g/s 10245Kp/s 10245Kc/s 10245KC/s _09..*7!vamos!
Session completed.
```

Comment: Why do you think something is wrong. Whenever asking for troubleshooting help, *always* include the command you used. Also, is the password in the wordlist you gave it?

Comment: ... is the password in the wordlist you gave it?

Comment: I tried to crack so many passwords. nearly all of them are included in the wordlist. however, it didn't work with me. I don't know what the problem is. can you help?

Comment: Not if the password is not in the rockyou wordlist ...

Comment: Add `--show` to print out the password if the hash is already cracked

Comment: Unless your wordlist is in your home directory, you don't want the ~ in your path for the wordlist.  Try removing the tilde and see what happens.

Comment: I'm not an expert in this format, but isn't [aad3b435b51404eeaad3b435b51404ee](https://yougottahackthat.com/blog/339/what-is-aad3b435b51404eeaad3b435b51404ee) the LM hash for an empty/non-password? (Maybe the NT hash is more interesting? That one at least has no hits from web searches.)